# Skeleton Library - Extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I was building an application using SkeletonView library, but unfortunately it throws me error during project is building...

The error is in the file named `RecursiveProtocol.swift`

Here is how that file looks like

```
import UIKit

typealias VoidBlock = () -> Void
typealias RecursiveBlock<T> = (T) -> Void

protocol IterableElement {}
extension UIView: IterableElement {}
extension CALayer: IterableElement {}

//MARK: Recursive
protocol Recursive {
   associatedtype Element: IterableElement
   func recursiveSearch(leafBlock: VoidBlock, recursiveBlock: 
   RecursiveBlock<Element>)
}


// Error block is here....
extension Array: Recursive where Element: IterableElement {
    func recursiveSearch(leafBlock: VoidBlock, recursiveBlock: 
         RecursiveBlock<Element>) {
         guard count > 0 else {
          leafBlock()
          return
        }
       forEach { recursiveBlock($0) }
    }
 }
```

Here is its picture
[image]

Comment: inheritance if for subclassing, otherwise you have to use protocols.

Comment: How to do it sir? I was trying to read document but not help

Comment: Your code compiled fine in my playground.

Comment: Oh my god.. I have edited my question. Pls check it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use later Xcode version, it works fine in Xcode 9.4